# Knockoutjs apply biding to multiple html nodes

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have multiple view models to that I'm running on a page, to fix any potential conflicts I added the parent html node to the knockout apply bindings text. However one of the issues I ran into was I can no longer a property that is outside one of those nodes. I'm trying to figure out if there is any way to update a single html node outside of the view model binding that I've bound that model too.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function VM1() {
            this.ViewModelProp1 = ko.observable(1);
            this.NotficationsNumber = ko.observable(1);
        }
        function VM2() {
            this.ViewModelProp2 = ko.observable(1);
        }
        ko.applyBindings(VM1, document.getElementById('vm1'));
        ko.applyBindings(VM1, document.getElementById('vm2'));
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- I want this property applied to the VM1 -->
    <h1 id="notifiy" data-bind="text: NotficationsNumber"></h1>
    <p id="vm1">
        <strong data-bind="text: ViewModelProp1"></strong>
    </p>
    <p id="vm2">
        <strong data-bind="text: ViewModelProp2"></strong>
    </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just create a single a little more complex ViewModel.

Comment: Dos you solve that? please read the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put it in its own container.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function VM1() {
            this.ViewModelProp1 = ko.observable(1);
            this.NotficationsNumber = ko.observable(1);
        }
        function VM2() {
            this.ViewModelProp2 = ko.observable(1);
        }
        ko.applyBindings(VM1, document.getElementById('div1'));
        ko.applyBindings(VM1, document.getElementById('vm2'));
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- I want this property applied to the VM1 -->
  <div id='div1'>
     <h1 id="notifiy" data-bind="text: NotficationsNumber"></h1>

    <p id="vm1">
        <strong data-bind="text: ViewModelProp1"></strong>
    </p>
</div>
<p id="vm2">
    <strong data-bind="text: ViewModelProp2"></strong>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the same view model in more than one place, i.e. just add

```
ko.applyBindings(VM1, document.getElementById('notify'));
```

Btw, you have 'notifiy' in your HTML :)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply binding in each node in the DOM, but what you want is change another viewModel bonded in the DOM, right? So you can use `ko.dataFor(element)` that will get the view model bonded in the element, see the snippet: 
see the snippet:

> Note: *it is one of the approachs to solve that.*

```js
function VM1() {
  this.ViewModelProp1 = ko.observable("VM 1");
  this.NotficationsNumber = ko.observable("VM 1");
}
function VM2() {
  this.ViewModelProp2 = ko.observable("vm2");
}

function updater(){
   this.textUpdate = ko.observable("Update");
   this.textUpdate.subscribe(function(nvalue){
       var vm1 = ko.dataFor( document.getElementById('div1'));
       vm1["ViewModelProp1"](nvalue);
   },this);  
};

ko.applyBindings(new updater(), document.getElementById('updater'));
ko.applyBindings(new VM1(), document.getElementById('div1'));
ko.applyBindings(new VM2(), document.getElementById('vm2'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
       
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div id="updater">
    <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: textUpdate"/>
  </div>
  
<!-- I want this property applied to the VM1 -->
  <div id='div1'>
     <h1 id="notifiy" data-bind="text: NotficationsNumber"></h1>

    <p id="vm1">
        <strong data-bind="text: ViewModelProp1"></strong>
    </p>
</div>
<p id="vm2">
    <strong data-bind="text: ViewModelProp2"></strong>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```